# ¿Cómo podría imprimir el número menor de una matriz junto con toda la fila y toda la columna donde se encuentra?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class e8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0, m = 0, menor = 0;
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el numero de filas"));
        m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el numero de columnas"));
        int matriz[][] = new int[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el valor de la fila " + i + " en la columna " + j));

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {

                    menor = matriz[i][j];
                }
                if (matriz[i][j] < menor) {
                    menor = matriz[i][j];
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AL igual que hacer para guardar el menor, puedes ir guardando la fila y la columna, por ejemplo:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class e8 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0, m = 0, menor = 0;
    int fila=0,columna=0; //variables auxiliares
    n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el numero de filas"));
    m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el numero de columnas"));
    int matriz[][] = new int[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el valor de la fila " + i + " en la columna " + j));

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {

                menor = matriz[i][j];
            }
            if (matriz[i][j] < menor) {
                menor = matriz[i][j];
                fila=i; //actualizamos la fila y la columna
                columna=j;
            }
    }
    //Pintamos la fila y columna del menor
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //if(i!=fila) //para no pintar la fila con el menor
        System.out.println(matriz[i][columna]); //Pintamos la columna entera
    }
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
       //if(j!=columna) //para no pintar la celda con el menor
       System.out.println(matriz[fila][j]); //Pintamos la fila entera 
    }
    //System.out.println(matriz[fila][columna]); //Pintamos la celda con el menor
}
```

Entiendo que quieres pintar algo como esto (sólo las que están en azul):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta amigo, lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo ya tengo guardado el numero menor pero tambien quiero imprimir toda la fila y toda la columna donde se encuentra situado este

Comment: Edito con la nueva versión. Como comentario te he dejado como se haría para mostrar solo 1 vez la celda con el menor. Espero que resuelva tu duda.

Comment: Exacto amigo justo le que quería hacer, muchas gracias me has salvado

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Documentación de código e imagen =0, saludos.